# Bad memory address when allocating OpenCL buffer

Tags: c++, opencl

I have a program running some image treatment with OpenCL, I sometimes have a crash because it's trying to write something into a memory address (with clCreateBuffer) that is null.

Is their any OpenCL call I can use to delay that memory write, or is it possible to check via C++ if a memory address is valid ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably can use OpenCL events.

```
cl_int clWaitForEvents (cl_uint num_events,
    const cl_event *event_list)
```

You can create an event from the call or operation you want to wait for, then before creating your buffer you wait for that event to complete.

However, could you provide a little bit of information. For example what exactly do you want to do? Maybe there is another way. It would also be better if you have some code showing your operations.

Comment: Due to some restrictions, I can't show any code, but I've tried the clWaitForEvents function and it seems to have solve my problem